# Last digit of 1/3

Tags: arithmetic

I stumbled upon a very bizarre result when playing with wolfram alpha. 
According to it, the [last digit of $\frac{1}{3} = 7$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=last+digit+of+3%5E(-1)).
Is that true? If yes, is there a mathematical argument for such a result?

The reason I require an explanation for such a statement is that the impression is that the theoretical definition of infinite decimal expansion suggests that the last digit should be 3. Moreover, if we force a different number, (mostly used by calculators) to terminate the decimal expansion in the manner $0.333333....4$, since it's more "sensible" for a calculator, even such an argument motivates the use of $4$ as the last digit. So why $7$?

Comment: In its usual decimal expansion $1/3$ has no last digit. Looks like WA is not programmed to answer "does not exist" :-) My guess is that $7$ pops out because it is the modular inverse of $3$ (modulo ten).

Comment: Never trust a software with such things :p

Comment: Yes, there is no “last” digit of $1/3$. Granted, it’s decimal respresentation, being $0.\bar{3}$, can be rounded to $0.333\dots 4$ at an arbitrary decimal place if one wants to write it out in a finite number of places. But, I am not sure why Wolfram would yield seven.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Can anyone of you provide a small answer to this question which I can accept and mark closure to this question? Or should I just delete it?

Comment: @Crosby, the decimal representation of $1/3$ is $0.333...$

Comment: @Green Oh, I need to go back to elementary school lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the last digit of $n$ is $d$, then this means $n\equiv d \pmod{10}$.

Now $3\cdot 7 = 21 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$, therefore it makes sense to say $1/3\equiv 7 \pmod{10}$ (note that $\gcd(3,10)=1$, therefore it actually makes sense to speak of an inverse of $3$ modulo $10$).

Interpreting “last digit of” as “the single digit number which the number is equivalent to module $10$” then gives the Wolfram result.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely Wolfram Alpha computed the modular inverse of $3 \bmod 10$, which is $7$.